# c++ /clrIntelliSense: no operator "+" matches these operands. System::Double ^ + System::Double ^

Tags: c++-cli

```
String ^ name;
Double^ math;
Double ^ physics;
Double ^ english;
Double ^ chemistry;
Double ^ cs;
Double ^ avrg;
Double ^ grade;  

name = this->name->Text;
math = Convert::ToDouble(this->textmath->Text);
physics = Convert::ToDouble(this->phis->Text);
english = Convert::ToDouble(this->eng->Text);
chemistry = Convert::ToDouble(this->chem->Text);
cs = Convert::ToDouble(this->cstf->Text);

Double^ sum = (math + physics + english + chemistry + cs) / 5;
```

On the last operation with Double ^sum an error appears:
               1    IntelliSense: no operator "+" matches these operands
                 operand types are: System::Double ^ + System::Double ^ 
Can you help me in finding an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using objects for the doubles?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use objects!

```
String ^ name = this->name->Text;
Double math = Convert::ToDouble(this->textmath->Text);
Double physics = Convert::ToDouble(this->phis->Text);
Double english = Convert::ToDouble(this->eng->Text);
Double chemistry = Convert::ToDouble(this->chem->Text);
Double cs = Convert::ToDouble(this->cstf->Text);

Double sum = (math + physics + english + chemistry + cs) / 5.0;
```